# Where is the map for all Java certificates?

Tags: java, certificate, scjp

I wanna know study what to get which certificate in Java ..

I need a map of Java certificates , i know that there are SCJP and others but i don't know what it require one to know in order to pass its exam ...

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: java certification]

Source: [Certification Overiew](https://education.oracle.com/).

Comment: <Sigh> Beat out for the rep by the "pretty" picture.  :-(

Comment: a picture is worth a couple of rep, if not a thousand words ;).

Answer (score 1):

http://in.sun.com/training/certification/java/scjp.xml

http://in.sun.com/training/certification/java/scjd.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

[Java Certification Paths](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=365)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Sun/Oracle Java certification overview](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=365).